# Open PDF crash on OS X

Tags: java, macos, pdf, file-io

I try to open a pdf file with java, it works good on Windows but on Mac, if the pdf reader is not open, the pdf does not open.

I tried a lot of ways to open the file like :

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
```

or

```
String[] cmd = new String[]{"/usr/bin/open", file.getPath};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

I also tried to open preview (mac pdf reader) before opening the file :

```
String openPreview = "/Applications/Preview.app/Contents/MacOS/Preview";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(openPreview);
String[] cmd = new String[]{"/usr/bin/open", "-a", "preview", file.getPath};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

But nothing is working... I have no other ideas and I don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: You need to say more about what you mean by "it doesn't work".  Does it crash, does it return null silently, does it crash your system, does it cause power to go out in the building?  Is there an error message, a stack trace; if so what are they?  This is also a perfect place for posting a small, self-contained, compilable example (SSCCE), which potential volunteer helpers can then put on their systems to see what they can figure out about it.

Comment: i got this syslog :
Jun  5 11:25:41 macNicolo sandboxd[39334] ([39331]): Preview(39331) deny file-read-data /Users/Nicolo/Library/Application Support/Oracle/Java/Deployment/cache/6.0/bundles

Jun  5 11:25:41 macNicolo Preview[39331]: No Info.plist file in application bundle or no NSPrincipalClass in the Info.plist file, exiting

Jun  5 11:25:41 macNicolo com.apple.launchd.peruser.503[560] ([0x0-0x19c69c5].com.apple.Preview[39331]): Exited with code: 1

Comment: Try looking at that from the standpoint of someone who knows nothing of your problem, and see if you honestly think they're going to exert much effort to help you out.  You need to improve the quality of your question(s) if you want help here.  Most folks here won't even tell you this much -- obviously...